# Who is Tripura Sundari?

Tags: temple, shakti

I am from Tripura.Our (unofficial) state goddess is [Tripura Sundari devi.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripura_Sundari_Temple)

Due to the similarity in appearance, people of our state think that she is an another form of Kali.

But Wikipedia says that she actually gave birth to all other gods and goddess.

So,Who is our state goddess actually?

[image]

Comment: The goddess wiki is talking and you are worshipping are different. Wiki is talking about Lalita Tripura sundari discussed in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/how-did-tripura-sundari-come-into-existence). You are talking about deity at Shaktipeetha. Shakti peethas are formed when the parts of Sati(previous birth of Goddess parvati) fell at certain places.

Comment: different names for the Divine Mother.

Comment: 'Tripura' - 'three towns' is another vedic way of saying 'triloka' - 'three worlds'; which refers to the earth, sky, and heavens. 'Sundari' - is the 'fairest one' or 'fairest female'. The fairest female in the three worlds is the Divine Mother.

Comment: Do you want to know about  the temple history or only who is tripura sundari?

Comment: Due to influence of kali worship in the east tripura is resembling as kali here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tripura Sundari or Lalita Mahatripura Sundari is the presiding Deity of the [Sri Yantra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Yantra) Or the Sri Chakra.She is also known as Parabhattarika Sri Rajarajeswari or the queen of queens.

She appeared to eradicate a most powerful demon called the Bhandasura, who was impossible to be defeated even by the Trinities(Brahma,Vishnu,Mahesha) and their respective consorts.

You can read a summary of what actually led to the manifestation of Parashakti (The force of the Parabrahman,Mahashambhu) as Sri Lalita Devi in [this](http://www.astrojyoti.com/brahmandapurana-3.htm)  Brahmanda Purana chapter.

Lalita Parameswari appeared from a Homa Kunda unto which the whole of creation was offered as oblation.

> **H.  At the end of this great fire sacrifice, all of you (the performers
>   of the Yaga) should jump in to the Homa Kunda (fire pit). While doing
>   so, you must possess absolute devotion.**
>
> **I. Then, Lalita Parameshwari will manifest.**
>
> J. She will be seated in a chariot called Chakra Raja Ratha.
>
> K. She will create Parabrahma in the name of Kameshwara and will have
>   Him as Her consort.
>
> L. This couple will re-create the entire universe, which will turn out
>   to be more beautiful than the previous creation.
>
> M. Lalita Parameshwari will bring Manmatha back to life.

```
But Wikipedia says that she actually gave birth to all other gods and goddess.
```

This is also true.Sri Lalita created Kameswara(or the Supreme Shiva or Sadashiva )from herself.And she created all other Gods from her body's various parts as mentioned below:

> The Lalita Parameshwari so manifested, **created a male form from
>   within Herself. His name was Kameshwara**. By her power of will, she
>   created 4 different weapons.
>
> A. **From the left eye**, which was of the nature of Soma (moon)
>   **came Brahmaand Lakshmi Devi.**
>
> B. **From the right eye**, which was of the nature of Soorya (sun)
>   **came Vishnu and Parvati.**
>
> C. **From the third eye**, which was of the nature of Agni (fire),
>   **came Rudra and Sarasvati.**
>
> D. Lakshmi & Vishnu, Shiva & Parvati and Brahma & Sarasvati became
>   couples.
>
> .................................................................
>
> E. Lalita Devi directed them to continue the process of Creation. She
>   herself continued to create certain things.
>
> (i) From her long hair she created darkness.
>
> (ii) From her eyes, she created the sun, the moon and the fire.
>
> (iii) From the pendent hanging in front of her forehead came the
>   stars.
>
> (iv) From the chain above her forehead came the nine planets.
>
> (v) From the eyebrows, she created the penal code.
>
> (vi) From her breath, she created the Vedas.
>
> (vii) From her speech, she created poetry and plays.
>
> (viii) From her chin she created the Vedangas.
>
> ........................................................
>
> (ix) From the three lines in her neck, she created various Shaastras.
>
> (x) From her breasts, she created mountains.
>
> (xi) From her mind, she created the power of bliss.
>
> (xii) **From her fingernails, she created the 10 incarnations of
>   Vishnu.**
>
> (xiii) From her palms, she created the Sandhyas.
>
> (xiv) She created other things as narrated in the Purusha Sookta.
>
> (xv) **From her heart, she created Baalaa Devi.**
>
> (xvi) **From her intellect, she created Shyamala Devi.**
>
> (xvii) **From her ego, she created Vaaraahi Devi.**
>
> (xviii) **From her smile, she created Vighneshwara.**
>
> (xix) From the Ankusha (a special hook), she created Sampatkaree Devi.
>
> (xx) Form the noose, she created Ashwaa Roodha Devi.
>
> (xxi) From her cheeks, she created Nakuleshvari Devi.
>
> (xxii) From her Kundalini Shakti, she created Gayatri.

And among the  [Dasamahavidyas](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Dasa_Maha_Vidhya_Sthuthi) her form is adored as the 16 year old Goddess Shodashi.

> 4.Shodasa Kala paripoorne AAdhya Shakthi roopini , Sri Vidhya Pancha vakthra nama Vikhyathe , Shodasi namosthuthe
>
> Salutations to the Goddess Shodasi , Who has completed sixteen years
>   of age , Who has the l,ook of the primeval power , Who is well known
>   as Srividhya and Panchavakthra

So,your state Goddess is the most supreme  Deity Sri Lalita who is the source of all that exists and who is constantly served by other Goddesses like Saraswati and Lakshmi.

Comment: Nice answer. But It seems that OP wants to know about the shaktipeetha at his place. You may add about Shakti peethas also if you like. .

Comment: @SreeCharan Where did OP ask about Shakti Peeta?

Comment: @TheDestroyer He linked the wiki article of the Tripura sundari temple instead of tripura sundari. The image is the deity in that temple. "Who is our state goddess actually?"- By this it implies that he wanted to know about the deity in the temple too. This sentence from OP makes the duplicate flags invalid.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, Both the deities have the same name.I am asking about the deity in the image and Wikipedia link.

Comment: @Kai She is same as Lalitha Tripura Sundari.